# Is this horrifying XSS vector still an issue in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xss

From hi.baidu.com/monyer/blog/item/d0f5d8b48fc442758bd4b2a4.html

> Char 192 is `<font face="xyz[0xC0]">not </font><font face=" onmouseover=alert(192) s=[0xC0]"     >available</font>`
>
> 0xC0 is one of the 32 first bytes of 2-byte sequences (0xC0-0xDF) in UTF-8. So when IE parses the above code, it will consider 0xC0 and the following quote as a sequence, and therefore these two pairs of FONT elements will become one with `"xyz[0xC0]">not </font><font face="` as the value of FACE parameter. The second 0xC0 will start another 2-byte sequence as a value of NOTEXIST parameter which is not quoted. Due to a space character following by the quote, 0xE0-0xEF which are first bytes of 3-byte sequences, together with the following quote and one space character will be considered as the value of NOTEXIST parameter.

Essentially, certain bytes indicate the start of a 3-byte character in a UTF-8 string. If those bytes make their way onto a webpage, IE will eat up the next two bytes *even if the resulting three bytes don't make up a valid UTF-8 character*. This can cause IE to eat up ending quotes in HTML attributes, wreaking XSS-flavored havoc.

The article is about IE6, so I have two tightly-coupled questions:

1. Is this still an issue in later versions of IE?
2. If so, is there a purely client-side method of avoiding it? In other words, assuming a "poisoned" string is received from the server, is there anything that can be done client-side to prevent this vulnerability?

Comment: @Karl I appreciate the edit, but I was trying to avoid linking to that site, as it seemed to be a bit seedy. I'm not sure about the rules regarding linking to sites here. Do you think it should be link (honest question)?

Comment: The page is indeed seedy :) I don't know if there are any rules, so let's rather not link it.

Comment: Could be I have no idea what's actually going on. But I tried this on JSFiddle in IE9, and there was no mouseover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the vulnerability correctly, it was addressed in 2006 in [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS06-021](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms06-021.mspx).

*A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way Internet Explorer decodes specially crafted UTF-8 encoded HTML. An attacker could exploit the vulnerability by constructing a specially crafted Web page that could potentially allow remote code execution if a user visited the specially crafted Web site.*

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. The date of the security bulletin is 2006/06/13; the date of the article is 2006/08/7. Additionally, the posts in [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg38279.html) mailing list – discussing the same vulnerability – are **also** from August. Additionally, some recent XSS-related chatter on tech blogs have mentioned this issue, referencing the originally cited article. This makes me wonder whether the issue has actually been resolved. Sadly, I don't have a Windows machine to test this on (and I'm not sure how I'd insert those invalid bytes).

Comment: The timing implies to me that the articles were written in response to the bulletin.